# How to select first row that matches MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have this tables

```
Product          |   prdImg
-------------------------------
id               | id
price            | imgRoute
name             | idPrd
idCategory       |
```

And I'm working with this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE productsByCat(
    IN idCat INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT id , name, price FROM Product WHERE idCategory = idCat;
END;;
```

Now, a product can have none or many images.
How can I add the FIRST image where prdImg.idPrd = product.id to that query?

Comment: And you specifically want to wrap this up in a procedure?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm open to different solutions

Comment: I don’t understand. Where does idcat get populated from?

Comment: from the application, the user selects a category from a combo @Strawberry

Comment: What language is the application?

Comment: That it's not that relevant to the question, but it's being build in Ionic, and the backend it's being managed in Php

Comment: So why not execute the query in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE productsByCat(
        IN idCat INT
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT id , name, price FROM Product WHERE idCategory = idCat AND product.id != YOURNULLORNOTEMPTYVALUE 
LIMIT 1;
END;;
```

I'd try that

Comment: The procedure already gives me the products that I want, what i need is to add from the other table the first image that matches the product id